# Change IP address using tor c#

Tags: c#, windows, tor

i want to change ip at x time interval using TOR and c# in windows platform can anyone help me regarding this??

TIA.

i tried this code

```
public string Refresh()
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", 9051);
    string response = string.Empty;
    string authenticate = MakeTcpRequest("AUTHENTICATE\r\n", client);
    if (authenticate.Equals("250"))
    {
        response = MakeTcpRequest("SIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n", client);
    }
    client.Close();
    return response;
}

public string MakeTcpRequest(string message, TcpClient client)
{
    client.ReceiveTimeout = 20000;
    client.SendTimeout = 20000;
    string proxyResponse = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        // Send message
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
        streamWriter.Write(message);
        streamWriter.Flush();

        // Read response
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
        proxyResponse = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Ignore
    }

    return proxyResponse;
}
```

and i get 514 authentication required error

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745268/how-to-use-tor-control-protocol-in-c

Answer (score 0):

What is your torrc? Without that it's tricky to help you. For examples of authenticating see...

https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#can-i-interact-with-tors-controller-interface-directly

More generally though if you simply want to cycle circuits at a certain interval then that's what the MaxCircuitDirtiness torrc option does...

https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#MaxCircuitDirtiness